# Mysterious issue with section numbering format

Tags: sectioning, numbering, tcolorbox

**I think this simple code snippet will do to define my problem:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside,reqno]{extbook}
\usepackage[margin=28mm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathpazo}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% ___Theorem box. Box with shaded left margin. By Spiritualis.
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{mygrey}{RGB}{127,127,127}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section]{mytheorem}[1][]
{
    enhanced jigsaw,colback=white,colframe=mygrey,coltitle=mygrey,coltext=darkgray,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    sharp corners,
    detach title,
    leftrule=16mm,
    underlay unbroken and first={\node[below,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center]
        at ([xshift=-8mm,yshift=-1mm]interior.north west) {\rotatebox{90}{Theorem \thetcbcounter}};},
    breakable,pad at break=1mm,
    #1,
    code={\ifdefempty{\tcbtitletext}{}{\tcbset{before upper={\tcbtitle\par\medskip}}}},
}
%__________________________________________________

% ---------------------------------=oo0oo=---------------------------------
\begin{document}
        
    % Section style definition
    \titleformat{\section}
    {\normalsize \bfseries}
    {\color{black} \S \hspace{.6pt} \thesection}
    {1ex}{\color{black}}[\quad]
    
    % Subsection style definition
    \titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalsize \bfseries}
    {\color{black} $ \bullet $ \thesubsection}
    {1ex}{\color{black}}[\quad]
    
    \renewcommand\thepart{\Roman{part}.}
    \renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}.}
    \renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}
            
    \section{Test for the format outside mytheorem box.}

    \subsection{My format for subsections.\\
}

    But inside mytheorem box...
    \\
    \section{Test for the format inside mytheorem box.
    }
    
    \begin{mytheorem}[title=Fundamental theorem for polygonal orthotransforms.]
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{mytheorem}
\vspace{2ex}

Why is the title format inside the box like this: Theorem 0.2..1?\\

Why is the title of the section \S \ 0.2 outside the left margin?
    
\end{document}
```

[image: This is what I get with this code:]

Comment: The first document level in a book is `\chapter`. `\section` and `\subsection` are only below that. If you don't need chapters, use an appropriate class, like `report` or `article`. Secondly, change `\titleformat{\section}[runin]` to `\titleformat{\section}`.

Comment: ingmar, this is only a fragment of a very complex document...

Comment: Simon, as I also said to ingmar, this is only  a fragment of the entire document, with parts, chapters, sections, ....

Comment: Sorry, we really can't account for code that you haven't posted. What about an MWE that actually shows your issue?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Try this code. Defines the `number freestyle` to format the theorem number.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside,reqno]{extbook}
\usepackage[margin=28mm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathpazo}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% ___Theorem box. Box with shaded left margin. By Spiritualis.
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{mygrey}{RGB}{127,127,127}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section,
number freestyle={\noexpand\thesection\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}}]{mytheorem}[1][]% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
{
    enhanced jigsaw,colback=white,colframe=mygrey,coltitle=mygrey,coltext=darkgray,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    sharp corners,
    detach title,
    leftrule=16mm,
    underlay unbroken and first={\node[below,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center]
        at ([xshift=-8mm,yshift=-1mm]interior.north west) {\rotatebox{90}{Theorem \thetcbcounter}};},
    breakable,pad at break=1mm,
    #1,
    code={\ifdefempty{\tcbtitletext}{}{\tcbset{before upper={\tcbtitle\par\medskip}}}},
}
%__________________________________________________

% ---------------------------------=oo0oo=---------------------------------
\begin{document}
    
    % Section style definition
    \titleformat{\section}
    {\normalsize \bfseries}
    {\color{black} \S \hspace{.6pt} \thesection}
    {1ex}{\color{black}}[\quad]
    
    % Subsection style definition
    \titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalsize \bfseries}
    {\color{black} $ \bullet $ \thesubsection}
    {1ex}{\color{black}}[\quad]
    
    \renewcommand\thepart{\Roman{part}.}
    \renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}.}
    \renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}
    
    \section{Test for the format outside mytheorem box.}
    
    \subsection{My format for subsections.\\
    }
    
    But inside mytheorem box...
    \\
    \section{Test for the format inside mytheorem box.
    }
    
    \begin{mytheorem}[title=Fundamental theorem for polygonal orthotransforms.]
            \lipsum[2]
    \end{mytheorem}
    \vspace{2ex}
    
    Why is the title format inside the box like this: Theorem 0.2..1?\\
    
    Why is the title of the section \S \ 0.2 outside the left margin?
    
\end{document}
```

Try this code. Defines the number freestyle to format the theorem number.

Comment: Thanks for your time, Simon, but I wish to preserve the general format I defined for my book. Obviously, if I delete the point after the definitions of section and subsections I solve the problem inside "mytheorem" box, but I don't want to change the global format.

Comment: @Jesús Álvarez Lobo Code updated.

Comment: Great Simon! Almost what I was looking for. The only difference is that I should add a period to the right, but this is solved straightforwardly: number freestyle={\noexpand\thesection\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}.}]{mytheorem}[1][] % added by Simon Dispa <<< Thank you very much for your valuable collaboration. Kind regards from Spain.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside,reqno]{extbook}
\usepackage[margin=28mm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathpazo}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% ___Theorem box. Box with shaded left margin. By Jesús Álvarez Lobo.
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{graytitle}{RGB}{127,127,127}
\definecolor{graytext}{RGB}{121,121,121}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section,
number freestyle={ \noexpand\thesection\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}.}]{mytheorem}[1][] % added by Simon Dispa <<<
{
    enhanced jigsaw,colback=white,colframe=graytitle,coltitle=graytitle,coltext=graytext,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    sharp corners,
    detach title,
    leftrule=16mm,
    underlay unbroken and first={\node[below,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center]
        at ([xshift=-8mm,yshift=-1mm]interior.north west) {\rotatebox{90}{$ \bullet $ Theorem \thetcbcounter}};},
    breakable,pad at break=1mm,
    #1,
    code={\ifdefempty{\tcbtitletext}{}{\tcbset{before upper={\tcbtitle\par\medskip}}}},
}
%__________________________________________________

% ---------------------------------=oo0oo=---------------------------------
\begin{document}
        
    % Section style definition
    \titleformat{\section}
    {\normalsize \bfseries}
    {\color{black} \S \hspace{.6pt} \thesection}
    {1ex}{\color{black}}[\quad]
    
    % Subsection style definition
    \titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalsize \bfseries}
    {\color{black} $ \bullet $ \thesubsection}
    {1ex}{\color{black}}[\quad]
    
    \renewcommand\thepart{\Roman{part}.}
    \renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}.}
    \renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}
            
    \section{Test for the format outside mytheorem box.}

    \subsection{My format for subsections.\\
}

    But inside mytheorem box...
    \\
    \section{Test for the format inside mytheorem box.
    }
    
    \begin{mytheorem}[title=Fundamental theorem for polygonal orthotransforms.]
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{mytheorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]